# How can I load last state when user presses back button in google chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, browser-history

I want the browser to load the last state of my web page when the user presses back button. My code works good when user is still in my page. But when it presses the Go link and goes to google.com and then presses back, he/she sees counter = 0 not the number it was when he left the page.

This is a sample program. In the real example I want to do this in a shopping website that when a user presses the add to cart button then it performs an ajax request and updates the page accordingly but after it goes to some other page and then presses back button he/she sees that he has nothing in his cart and its not what we wanted.

```html
<span id="counter">0</span>
<button onclick="add_counter();">+</button>

<a href="https://google.com">Go!</a>

<script>
    function add_counter() {
        var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
        counter.innerHTML = parseInt(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
        history.pushState({ number: counter.innerHTML }, null);
    }

    window.onpopstate = function (event) {
        var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
        if (event.state != null) {
            counter.innerHTML = event.state.counter;
        } else {
            counter.innerHTML = "0";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I think you have to save the current state to the local storage or a cookie or some form of local cache for it to be available when the user comes back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not willing to save data in the server, you can save this data in the **Local Storage** or the **Session Storage**.

When the page load again, just fetch the previous state from the storage.

You can find a good example on how to do this here: 
https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-use-local-storage-with-javascript/

demo: https://taniarascia.github.io/sandbox/tab/

Comment: I do save the data on server. But when you press back button, chrome uses cached version to load the page.

Comment: Hey try this, it will reload the page when the back button is pressed: https://codepen.io/derekjp/pen/Bguwz

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know, it is not possible transferring data from pages to each other using pure JS or HTML (not talking about cookies). 
JavaScript and HTML are frontend languages, which are meant to work only on the one specific open webpage. They will be reloaded once you open the webpage again, so unsaved information will be gone.

How to fix it?
In the end, you need to quicksave your data either on the server (AJAX) or at the user (cookies). This information can be read out, once the user comes back to your page.

Comment: I do save the data on server. But when you press back button, chrome uses cached version to load the page.

Comment: If you store the data on the server, that is an easy task. Personally I would use PHP. So you do not hardcode the start of your counter, you do more like this: `counter.innerHTML = "<?php echo (isset(num)) ? num : "0" ?>"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

- [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)
- [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
- [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

But pay attention to the fact that you can't use these features if user uses an incognito window in the browser